# Show/Hide spoilers on any site

Tags: script

### Screenshot

[image: spoiler]

**Click!**
[image: screenshot]

**Then...**

[image]

### About

This is a small script that add a button to show or hide the spoilers on any Stack Exchange site. The setting will then be remembered across the site.

### License

The MIT license.

### Download

You can download the Safari extension, [**here**](http://cl.ly/6wq1)

You can directly download the UserScript, [**here**](http://cl.ly/6xl7)

### Platform

**Google Chrome** (via the UserScript)
**Safari** (via the extension)

### Versions

#### v1.2

- Fixed a bug where links weren't visible
- Fixed bug where red left margin was not visible on some design

#### v1.1

Now use localStorage instead of cookies.

#### Known issue

- It does not work on previews

### Contact

You can ping me on twitter (see my profile).
I sometimes hang out on The Tavern.