# Show/Hide spoilers on any question (and its answers)

Tags: script, posts

#### About:

Inspired by [this feature request](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7888/31051) on Meta Science Fiction & Fantasy, this script adds a checkbox to the "question info" sidebar block on each question to allow toggling all spoiler blocks on the page.

[image: This script adds a checkbox to the question info sidebar]

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:

Here's what it looks like on [scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112783](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112783/31051) (the screenshots are quite a bit larger than the thumbnails below; click to embiggen):

- **Spoilers Enabled:**

  [image]
- **Spoilers Disabled:**

  [image]

#### Download / Install:

Install from GitHub: <kbd>[Install](https://github.com/jwbaker/stackexchange-toggle-spoilers/raw/master/script.user.js)</kbd>

Requires a UserScript manager (like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey).

#### Platform:

Developed and tested on Windows 10 and Chrome 54. It should work on all desktop operating systems and most browsers (IE version 5.5 or greater, Safari version 4 or greater).

Not tested on mobile.

#### License: MIT

#### Code:

Developed in native JavaScript. Code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/jwbaker/stackexchange-toggle-spoilers).

Any bugs can be reported in comments here, or in GitHub's issue tracker.

Related: [stackapps.com/q/2404](https://stackapps.com/q/2404/37723)